# How to change writable enumerable and configurable values of a Javascript object property?

Tags: javascript

From the node repl:

```
foo = { bar: 'baz'};
console.log (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'bar'))
```

Returned value:

```
{ value: 'baz',
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true }
```

How do you change the writable enumerable, and configurable to false? What are these values called? Are they part of ES5.1? Are there more that the repl didn't output?

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format your code, without italics, bold, etc...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *"How do you change the writable enumerable, and configurable to false?"*

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'baz', {
    enumerable:false,
    writable:false,
    configurable:false
});
```

There's also `Object.defineProperties`, which is the same, except you can set multiple properties, and `Object.create`, which let's you create a new object, and set its prototype object, and its descriptors.

> *"What are these values called?"*

They're property descriptors.

> *"Are they part of ES5.1?"*

Yes, ES5.

> "*Are there more that the repl didn't output?"*

More what, property descriptors? No.

Comment: i think this above method is not supported by IE8 but in classical ecmascript i.e. older versions can we control enumeration and configuration of properties?

Comment: How i can change descriptors of existing object?

Comment: @mqklin: This answer shows how. In the example, `foo` is the existing object, and `bar` is the property that is having its descriptors changed.

Answer (score 5):

squint:I think there is like a little typing error in your answer.

Your code:

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'baz', {
enumerable:false,
writable:false,
configurable:false
});
```

but the second argument must be the name of the property and not the value, so the correct code is:

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
enumerable:false,
writable:false,
configurable:false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add this in

You can change the attributes when first creating an object like so:

```
var newObj = Object.defineProperty({}, 'aPropertyName', {
    enumerable:false,
    writable:false,
    configurable:false
});
```

You can also, you can alter multiple properties at once:

```
var newObj = Object.defineProperties({}, {
    aPropertyName: {enumerable: false, writable: false, configurable: false},
    anotherPropertyName: {enumerable: true, writable: true, configurable: false},
    finalPropertyName: {enumerable: true, writable: false, configurable: true},
});
```

And of course passing in the object name with the previous method:

```
Object.defineProperties(objectName, {
    aPropertyName: {enumerable: false, writable: false, configurable: false},
    anotherPropertyName: {enumerable: true, writable: true, configurable: false},
    finalPropertyName: {enumerable: true, writable: false, configurable: true},
});
```